# Pie chart from Log Analytics aggregation

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring

I am trying to write a simple aggregation query in Kusto that would show me how many machines are at the moment alive, based on heartbeat.

I can get the alive status with the following query:

```
Heartbeat 
| summarize LastHeartbeat=max(TimeGenerated) by Computer
```

This yields output similar to:

Computer
LastHeartbeat [UTC]

VM1 5/4/2020, 3:23:40.227 PM
VM2 5/4/2020, 2:59:46.780 PM

But then I want to add a column that would be max(TimeGenerated) not by Computer, but in total. I was trying to do aggregation by multiple terms, but apparently this is not possible:

```
Heartbeat 
| summarize LastHeartbeat=max(TimeGenerated) by Computer, Latest=max(TimeGenerated)
| extend isAlive = (LastHeartbeat == Latest)
```

My question is - how can I use the data to render a pie chart showing alive/dead machines? How can I use this data to render a piechart showing ratio of OFF/ON machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
datatable(vm_id:string, dt:datetime)
[   
    'VM1', datetime(5/3/2020, 3:23:40.227 PM),
    'VM2', datetime(5/4/2020, 2:59:46.780 PM),
    'VM3', datetime(5/4/2020, 2:59:46.780 PM),
]
| as T // this is your summary table, where each vm_id has a single entry with its max datetime
| extend status = case(dt == toscalar(T | summarize max(dt)), "ON", "OFF") 
| summarize count() by status
| render piechart
```

[image]